# load dict every x seconds then pass to df and clear dict

Tags: python

I am trying to write values to a dictionary every 5 seconds for 1 minute. I then want to take those values and put into a dataframe to write to csv and clear the original dictionary and keep going.

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process

a = {'value':[], 'timeStamp': []}

def func1():
    global a
    print "starting First Function"
    a['value'].append(random.randint(1,101))
    a['timeStamp'].append(time.time()*1000.0)
    time.sleep(5)
    return a

def func2():
    print "starting Second Function"
    time.sleep(60)
    d = pd.DataFrame(a)
    print d
    # here i would write out the df to csv and del d
    a.update({}.fromkeys(a,0))
    print "cleared"


if __name__=='__main__':
while True:
    p1 = Process(target = func1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target = func2)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print "test"
    print a
```

This is where i'm at now, which may or may not be the correct way to do this. Regardless, this code is not giving me the correct results. I am trying to figure out the best way to get the dict into the df and clear it. Hopefully, someone has done something similar?

Comment: You do realise that ``a`` is not shared between processes? Is there a reason why you are not using threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes do not share memory - each function modifies a *separate* `a`. Therefore, changes are not seen across functions and the main process.

To share memory between your functions, use the `threading` module instead. You can test this in your example by replacing `Process` with `Thread`:

```
from threading import Thread as Process
```

This allows you to run your example unchanged otherwise.

---

Note that `threading` in Python is limited by the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf). Threads run concurrently, but not in parallel - Python code only ever runs on one core. Extensions and system calls such as `time.sleep` and the underlying data structures of `pandas` can sidestep this, however.

Comment: Reading through the threading docs actually cleared it up for me quite a bit, I think i was overthinking my problem. I rewrote using threading and it's much simpler. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code has so many problems that it is hardly suitable for any use. You may start your research with something like this (python 3, threads instead of processes):

```
import time
import random
import threading

def func1(a):
    print("starting First Function")
    for dummy in range(10):
        a['value'].append(random.randint(1, 101))
        a['timeStamp'].append(time.time() * 1000.0)
        time.sleep(1)
    print("stopping First Function")


def func2(a):
    print("starting Second Function")
    for dummy in range(2):
        time.sleep(5)
        print(a)
        a['value'] = list()
        a['timeStamp'] = list()
        print("cleared")
    print('stopping Second Function')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = {'value': list(), 'timeStamp': list()}

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=func1, args=(a,))
    t1.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=func2, args=(a,))
    t2.start()
```

The output is:

```
starting First Function
starting Second Function
{'value': [32, 95, 2, 71, 65], 'timeStamp': [1536244351577.3914, 1536244352584.13, 1536244353586.6367, 1536244354589.3767, 1536244355591.9202]}
cleared
{'value': [43, 44, 28, 69, 25], 'timeStamp': [1536244356594.6294, 1536244357597.2498, 1536244358599.9812, 1536244359602.9592, 1536244360605.9316]}
cleared
stopping Second Function
stopping First Function
```